# Does requirejs optimizer concatenate CSS files

Tags: css, optimization, requirejs

I've been playing with the requirejs optimizer. It works well for concatenating & minifying js files. Does it able to concatenate css files as well?

**EDIT:** I followed this [post](http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project) and I don't see the CSS files are getting concatenated.

**Project structure**

[image]

**Grunt config**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    bowercopy: {
        lib: {
            options: {
                destPrefix: 'src/js/lib'
            },
            files: {
                'jquery.js': 'jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'backbone.js': 'backbone/backbone.js',
                'underscore.js': 'underscore/underscore.js',
                'require.js': 'requirejs/require.js',
                'almond.js': 'almond/almond.js'
            }
        }
    },

    requirejs:  {
        compile: {
            options: {
                mainConfigFile : "src/js/main.js",
                appDir: "src",
                baseUrl: "js/lib",
                dir: "dist",
                optimize: "uglify2",
                optimizeCss: "standard",
                name: 'almond',
                include: ['../main'],
                insertRequire: ['../main']
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
};
```

After running `grunt requirejs` I see the js and css files are moved to `dist` folder but I dont see the concatenated CSS file.

Comment: I found a blog post which said it inlines any CSS files referenced by @import. I can't find any reference to that in the documentation, but it might be worth a try?

Comment: Thanks Olly. I don't understand why someone want to close this question.

Comment: Because you could have just checked the docs? [**Documentation**](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onecss)

Comment: Then half of the questions asked in SO has to be closed

Comment: @Paulie_D I've done quite amount of contribution to SO. Based on that I've a request. Before clicking the close button by just reading the description people has to put little effort to improve the question. Do you think I haven't read the documentation before answering this question? I couldn't get the answer from their docs or online blogs. It's sad all these moderation make people hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: I wouldn't know if you'd read the documentation because you didn't mention it. What if a new user had asked the same question. I'm entitled to a vote...it may not garner any others so the question will stay open.

Comment: @Paulie_D If a new user has asked the same question then you should mark this as a duplicate providing link to the other question. Also, one cannot provide every information at the time of composing the question. You should ask them to include more information to improve the question.

Comment: What other question? I didn't suggest it was a duplicate, I indicated that you were trying to find information that should, perhaps have been available offsite. Perhaps a comment as well  would have been polite...I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: A solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29028917/1254597

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem of the issue. The paths in the import statements of CSS files should be relative. In my case both the `style.css` and `thirdparty.css` files are located in the same folder.

In `style.css` i'm importing the `thirdparty.css` so it'll be,

```
@import url('thirdparty.css');

body {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

After running the grunt command now I see the styles of `thirdparty.css` are inlined in `style.css`.